# Is there a way to override the result event on Mapbox Geocoder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mapbox

I want to do something just before the animation of the map going to the searched location, so I want to know if is there a way to suspend that animation, or a way to achieve this, kind of delay that beahaviour.

I tried this but it's not working as intended:

```
geocoder.on('result', function(ev) {
    console.log("result> ", ev);
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("release after 2 seconds");
    }, 2000); 
    //debugger
});
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the Mapbox GL Geocoder plugin provides this kind of flexibility. As you can see in its [source code](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/blob/master/lib/index.js#L227), once the result is retrieved, it will just `flyTo` to its position.

A possible (but hacky) solution could be to use the [`movestart`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map.event:movestart) and [`map.stop()`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#stop) to stop the animation as soon as it begins, do you thing and then restart the animation manually.

But you are probably better off writing your own geocoder. It can be very easy with the [Mapbox Geocoder Javascript SDK](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-js).